# How to properly add inline js?

Tags: forms, javascript

```
function prospectpicker_unfollow_init() {
drupal_add_js($prospectpicker_unfollow_path . '/js/stickyMojo.js');
drupal_add_js('jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery("#unfollow-sidebar").stickyMojo({footerID: "#unfollow-footer", contentID:  "#unfollow-content"});
    });', 'inline');
}
```

I have included a js file named as "stickyMojo.js", and I want to use that js file's function named as stickyMojo, in order to add the sticky sidebar to my form elements.

Comment: Hello and welcome. This is Q&A site, not a helpdesk. Please edit your question to include all information needed to post an answer: how are you trying to use it, what's the error you are seeing in js console (or how do you know it fails), why are you using `$(document).ready()` instead of [behaviors](https://drupal.org/node/756722#behaviors), and why are you using `drupal_add_js` instead of [`#attached`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#attached) (it's tagged with Form API, so why not to use Form API?).

Answer (score 2):

Just a suggestion.

As `hook_init` is only called on non-cached page, and you require this JS to be called on every page; why don't you go ahead and add it to your theme's `.info` file?

```
scripts[] = js/stickyMojo.js
```

Comment: Actually, that's not good either. Might possibly work, but when js belongs to a form (OP tagged it with Form API), it should be attached to a form. Also, one of the main problems is using document ready - not all form elements are ready on document ready ;)

Comment: @ajit isn't the cached page will have the js already added ? I am not sure if js issue may occur because of caching or is it?

Comment: @arpitr Depends. If it's inside some conditional, then it's a bit of lottery. If form is in a block, it might be even worse. `drupal_add_js` should be the last choice for adding JS, just before editing it into a tpl file directly (that should be pretty much avoided totally).

Answer (score 2):

Where are you defining the `$prospectpicker_unfollow_path`?

To construct your path to a certain file of your module, you can use the `drupal_get_path` function of Drupal. In your case it would be:

```
function prospectpicker_unfollow_init() {
    drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'prospectpicker_unfollow') . '/js/stickyMojo.js');
    drupal_add_js('jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery("#unfollow-sidebar").stickyMojo({footerID: "#unfollow-footer", contentID:  "#unfollow-content"});
    });', 'inline');
}
```

Comment: i have used drupal_get_path but i have'nt mentioned it here.

Comment: Your js library `stickyMojo.js` is loaded? Do you any javascript errors when looking at console log?

Answer (score 2):

Just an addition to @Mike Vranckx's answer: 
We can use the [heredoc PHP syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) :

• is easier to read
• and to write ( quoting especially )

As well as to precise the scope ( eg : display the script in the footer )

```
function prospectpicker_unfollow_init() {
  $inlineJS = <<<EOT
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
      jQuery("#unfollow-sidebar").stickyMojo({
        footerID: "#unfollow-footer", 
        contentID: "#unfollow-content"
      });
    });
EOT;
  drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'prospectpicker_unfollow') . '/js/stickyMojo.js');
  drupal_add_js($inlineJS, 'inline');
  // We can tell as well where to display it ( eg : in the footer ) 
  // drupal_add_js( $inlineJS, [ 'type' => 'inline', 'scope' => 'footer', 'weight' => 5 ]);
}
```